# javascript set a variable value when enter is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am quite new to JavaScript, but I'm certain there has to be an easy way to set a variable value when enter is pressed in an HTML text input box.

```
<input type='text' name='userEntry' class='inner-choice-entry' placeholder='Type your answer here' />
```

And the following is running in the background, for example:

```
var userEntry;
function determineUserChoice(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
        userEntry = document.getElementsByName('userEntry').value;      
    }
};
```

The following will be used to display a message to the user and prompt them to enter a value:

```
displayedLine = 'Please enter your name.';
$('.inner-content-text').html(displayedLine);
displayedChoiceLine = 'Your name is:';
$('.inner-choice-text').html(displayedChoiceLine);
determineUserChoice();
charName = userEntry;
$('.inner-content-sidebar-text-playername').html(charName);
```

For the life of me, I cannot figure out to get the function 'determineUserChoice' to set the  'userEntry' variable to whatever the user has entered WHEN the enter key is pressed. There is probably an easier way to go about this. My goal is to have a series of questions posed to the user and then displayed on the page after the enter key has been pressed, followed by additional displayed messages.

Comment: How are you binding the function to a keyboard-related event?

Answer (score 2):

You can do the below.

Attach a Event Handler for key-down event on your text-box. I have used its `class='inner-choice-entry` to reference it.

```
$('.inner-choice-entry').keydown(determineUserChoice);
```

**Note:** If you are OK with adding an `id` attribute to your input field, you can use `$('#userEntry')` instead of `$('.inner-choice-entry')`.

Modify the `determineUserChoice` function as below. This is to overcome the point mentioned in Thierry J's answer. The `getElementsByName` method returns an array of all elements with the given name. Using `getElementsByName('userEntry')[0].value` will take the value of only the first such element with `name=userEntry`.

```
function determineUserChoice(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
        console.log('ok');
        userEntry = document.getElementsByName('userEntry')[0].value; //note the change here.
        console.log(userEntry);
    }
};
```

**Note:** Again as mentioned above, if you add an `id` to the field, you can get the value as follows.

```
userEntry = document.getElementById('userEntry').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
<input onkeypress="determineUserChoice(event)" type='text' name='userEntry' class='inner-choice-entry' placeholder='Type your answer here' />
```

Beware though, `document.getElementsByName(...)` returns an array of all element with the given name. Use `document.getElementById(...)` to return the only element with the given `id` in the page (as ids are to be unique in a page).

Comment: Where do you set the variable `e` in `determineUserChoice(e)`?

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByName` returns a `nodeList`, not a single element. You need to index it to get the element before getting its value, so it should be:

```
userEntry = document.getElementsByName('userEntry')[0].value;
```

I assume you're binding the handler with `addEventHandler` somewhere, and just didn't show that code.